# Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rubygems

In my gemfile:

`group :development, :test,:production do`
`gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.16'`
`end`

In logs:

`$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

`Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.3758
rake aborted!`

`Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'mysql' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is
at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).`

I have added "cleardb" add-on for the application.And now i want to use it.But, i am not able to migrate to database as i am getting above error.

Comment: show up your `database.yml`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you set your `DATABASE_URL`, you need to specify to use `mysql2://` instead of `mysql://`

Something like this:

`heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql2://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'`